# How to get {{text}} in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have code like this:

```
<my-button>{{text}}</my-button>  (The 'text' is not so sure, can be the other like: 'mytext')

myApp.directive("myButton", function(){
    function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs){
        //How to get the {{}} variable name and value?
        //not always '{{text}}' can be {{text1}}  {{text2}}
    }
    return {
        link: linkFunc,
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<button></button>,
        transclude: true,
        replace: true
    }
});
```

I know I can get the text using `element.text()` and recompile it in directive. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Is this a valid format? i mean .directive(function... and not .directive('name', function() { ... or .directive('name', functionName); function functionName () ...

Comment: @alou Just change it.Thx for your notice : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mark your directive as 'transclude' like you did, but you also need an insertion point for your content. In this case it's just inside the button so you could do something like this:

```
app.directive('myButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-transclude></button>',
        transclude: true
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c82stoqk/)

Answer (score 3):

You could try to pass it as an argument:

```
<my-button text="someText"></my-button> or
<my-button text="{{text}}"></my-button> 

myApp.directive('myButton', function(){
    function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs){
        //How to get the {{}} variable name and value?
        //not always '{{text}}' can be {{text1}}  {{text2}}
    }
    return {
        scope: { text: '@' },
        link: linkFunc,
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<button>{{text}}</button>,
        transclude: true,
        replace: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for your help. But I need to pass this element in  {{}}. : (

Comment: I think you should be able to do it with transclude as well, have you tried <my-button>Static text</my-button>, just to see if it transcludes?

Comment: Ok, I will try this later. Then I will let you know.

Comment: Tyler, you can use the {{}} notation in the argument also, I added a line in my answer, would that do it?